# Find n-level nested SubDocument MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have this Document:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "DocType": "Unidade",
  "Nome": "TONY",
  "RG_InscricaoEstadual": "4347924938742",
  "Setores": [
    {
      "$id": "9",
      "Nome": "Child0",
      "Setores": [
        {
          "$id": "10",
          "Nome": "Child1",
          "Setores": [
                     /* <n depth nested level> */
                     "$id": "11",
                     "Nome": "Child2",
                     "Id": "90228c56-eff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15c",
                     "DocType": "Setor"
          ],
          "Id": "60228c56-dff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15b",
          "DocType": "Setor"
        }
      ],
      "Id": "8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c",
      "DocType": "Setor"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to query this SubDocument if I want to retrieve a Setor, for example

```
"Id": "60228c56-dff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15b"
```

I know that if I know now many levels it is Nested, I can write a query to look for something like

```
Unidade.Setor.Id=="8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c"
```

But How can I search for it for a unknown number of nested Levels, for example 1, 2, 3 n levels?

How to find the Setor with **Id '90228c56-eff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15c'**, for example?

*Comments about how to solve this question will also be appreciated.*

Answer (score 3):

In c# we can create a recursive method to achieve this scenario.

Here is a BsonDocument I created:

```
 BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument {
            { "id","1"},
            { "DocType", "Unidade"},
            { "Nome", "TONY"},
            { "RG_InscricaoEstadual", "4347924938742"},
            { "Setores",new BsonArray {
             new BsonDocument {
             { "id","9" },
             { "Nome", "Child0"},
             { "Setores", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument {
                          { "id","10" },
                          { "Nome", "Child1"},
                          { "Setores", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument {
                                       { "id","11" },
                                       { "Nome", "Child2"},
                                       {  "Id","90228c56-eff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15c" },
                                       { "DocType", "Setor"}
                                       }
                                       }
                          },
                          {  "Id","60228c56-dff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15b" },
                          { "DocType", "Setor"}
                 }
                 }
                 },
                 {  "Id","8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c" },
                 { "DocType", "Setor"}
                 }
            }
            }
            };
```

You can use [Mongo c# Query method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/getting_started/quick_tour/#get-a-single-document-with-a-filter) to get this BsonDocument from MongoDB.

Here is a recursive method I used to query document via "Id": 
`BsonDocument result = GetID(doc, "90228c56-eff2-46d2-a324-b04e3c69e15c");`

```
 public static BsonDocument GetID(BsonDocument doc, string queryId)
    {
        BsonDocument result = new BsonDocument();
        if (doc.Elements.Where(c => c.Name == "Setores").Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in doc.GetElement("Setores").Value.AsBsonArray)
            {
                var id = item.AsBsonDocument.GetElement("Id").Value;
                if (id == queryId)
                {
                    result = item.AsBsonDocument;
                    break;
                }
                result = GetID(item.AsBsonDocument, queryId);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I hope this could give you some tips.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do is have nested queries i.e.

```
find({"Unidade.Setor.Id": ObjectId("8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c")
find({"Unidade.Setor.Setor.Id": ObjectId("8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c")
find({"Unidade.Setor.Setor.Setor.Id": ObjectId("8457e1b7-39dc-462c-8f46-871882faea2c")
```

Run then one after the other if the previous one fails.

***But DON'T!!!***

You should be storing these `Setor` records as separate documents. You can store them with references to each other and then query for them using lookup (like a join in SQL)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Good answer, can you please add some example of Lookup using the C# LINQ sintax for the MongoDB C# driver?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a node developer. I can only answer the mongo part.