# Retrieve and update sub document in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I would like to get from document only its sub document. I have structure like this:

```
{"_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9cdf",
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2018-04-17T22:17:53.696Z"),
"UpdatedDate" : ISODate("2018-04-17T22:17:53.698Z"),
"Label" : "2018-Q1",  
"Sections" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce0",
        "Label" : "TWN-25",
        "Groups" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce1",
                "Label" : "Group1"                    
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce2",
                "Label" : "Group 2"                    
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3",
                "Label" : "Group3"             
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce4",
        "Label" : "TWN-26",
        "Groups" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce5",
                "Label" : "Group4"    
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I have next find query

```
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq("_id", questionnaireId) & builder.Eq($"Sections._id", sectionId) &
            builder.Eq("Sections.Groups._id", groupId);
```

But I would like to get only `Group` sub document from document. For this I have to build Projection. Here is my projection:

`var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Sections.Groups.$");`

And I am calling it like this

`var result = Collection.Find(filter).Project(project).FirstOrDefault();`

But I am still getting all document, not just sub document `Group`. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Might want to take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549233/find-n-level-nested-subdocument-mongodb

Comment: @OrellBuehler I did not find there correct answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43581261/2703505  -  really strange approach. And here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552365/2703505  I would not reccoment using aggregation because it really load operation than just find

Comment: Ok, will look into it. To be sure, do you want the objects inside both "Groups" array?

Comment: @OrellBuehler  yes, I would like to get one Group as you can see from query .. I am sending Group Id

Comment: `            var filter = builder.Eq("_id", questionnaireId) & builder.Eq($"Sections._id", sectionId) &
                         builder.Eq("Sections.Groups._id", groupId).Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Groups"));` Can you try this?

Comment: result is {{ "_id" : "5ad728613db5d7001c196d36" }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169450/discussion-between-oleh-and-orell-buehler).

Comment: Use [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-arrayfilters), please note this feature is available from 3.6

Comment: @ClementAmarnath yes, I am using 3.6 but I would like to get sub document. Array filter is for update, is not it ?

Comment: Yes ArrayFilter is for update

Comment: @ClementAmarnath for update I am using my filter and set operation  like this   {$set:{"Sections.0.Groups.1": subDocument  }}  and it works ok, but I would like to have possibility to read only sub document

Comment: `Find` always return a top-level document. `Projection` limits fields returned, but does not change structure of the document. If you need groups as top-level documents of the cursor you should use `aggregation`.

Comment: @AlexBlex  so it it possible to receive such result  {"_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9cdf",
"Sections" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce0",
        "Groups" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce1",
                "Label" : "Group1"                    
            }
  ]
 }
]}  ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. `$` can be used for top-level arrays only. i.e. without aggregation the best you can get is `{"_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9cdf", "Sections" : [ { "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce0", "Groups" : [ { "_id" : "5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce1", "Label" : "Group1" }, {_id:.....}, {_id:.....},... ] } ]} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ideal world i would suggest you to use following query:

```
db.getCollection('Test').find(
{
        "Sections.Groups._id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3"
}, 
{ 
        "Sections.Groups": 
        {
                "$elemMatch" : {"_id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3" } 
        }
} )
```

But, unfortunately, you will get following exception:

```
Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field
```

You basically have two options:

Use **aggregation framework**

```
db.Test.aggregate( [
   {$match: { "Sections.Groups._id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3" } },   
   {$unwind: "$Sections"},
   {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Sections"} },
   {$unwind: "$Groups"},
   {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Groups"} },
   {$match: { "_id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3" }}
] )
```

Use following query

```
db.getCollection('Test').find(
{"Sections.Groups._id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3"}, 
{"Sections": {"$elemMatch" : {"Groups._id":"5ad6729179b9c00808ea9ce3" } }} )
```

I would go with first options, although it is not very efficient